# Additional attributes in Laravel all request

Tags: laravel, oop, model-view-controller, eloquent

Good day.
For example, I have a model `People` with fields/attributes:

```php
name
surname
```

and the model also has this method:

```php
public function FullName()
{
    return "{$this->name} {$this->surname}";
}
```

if I make the next request:

```php
$p = $people->all();
```

I'll get collection with names and surnames as attributes
how i can make function execution for each in `all()` request?

**What is the best practice?**

Comment: foreach ($peoples->all() as $people)
   {

       var_dump($people->name);
   }

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well, depends on what kind of result do you want.

---

### OPTION A: Have `name`, `surname` and `full_name` in all the items of the array.

Eleazar's answer is correct, but a little bit incomplete.

#### 1. Define a new accessor in your model.

This will define a new attribute in your model, just like `name` or `surname`. When the new attribute is defined, you can just do `$user->full_name` to get the attribute.

As the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) says, to define an accessor you need to add a method in your model:

```php
// The function name will need to start with `get`and ends with `Attribute`
// with the attribute field in-between in camel case.
public function getFullNameAttribute() // notice that the attribute name is in CamelCase.
{
    return $this->name . ' ' . $this->surname;
}
```

#### 2. Append the attribute to the model

This will make the attribute to be considered just like any other attribute, so whenever a record of the table is called, this attribute will be added to the record.

To accomplish this you'll need to add this new value in the protected `$appends` configuration property of the model, as you can see in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json):

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * The accessors to append to the model's array form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
     // notice that here the attribute name is in snake_case
    protected $appends = ['full_name'];
}
```

#### 3. Make sure that this attribute is `visible`

Notice this important part of the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-serialization#hiding-attributes-from-json):

> Once the attribute has been added to the appends list, it will be
> included in both the model's array and JSON representations.
> Attributes in the appends array will also respect the `visible` and
> `hidden` settings configured on the model.

#### 4. Query your data.

When doing the following:

```php
$p = $people->all();
```

The `$p` array should have `name`, `surname` and also the new `full_name` attribute for each item.

---

### OPTION B: Just get the full_name for specific purposes.

You can do the following when querying, iterate each result to get the attribute.

Now to do this you can iterate  the collection with a `foreach` sentence, but given that whenever querying data, the array returned is always a [Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-collections) instance, so you simply use the `map` function:

```php
$full_names = $p->map(function ($person) {
    // This will only return the person full name,
    // if you want additional information just custom this part.
    return $person->fullname;
});
```

Using [collection higher order messages](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#higher-order-messages) it can be even shorter:

```php
$full_names = $p->map->fullname;
```

Comment: Option B can be simplified to: `$full_names = $p->pluck('fullname');`. Even with an accessor that's been appended to the model.

Comment: @IvankaTodorova Notice that in my response Option B is independent of the steps of Option A, so the accesor isn't appended yet, but yeah, it could be easily accesed in the way you suggested :).

Comment: Almost everything is as it should, but it is necessary to represent the data in the form of the array or json

Comment: @DmitriySkogorev sorry, I didn't understand your last question.

Answer (score 2):

I use the following:

```
public function getFullNameAttribute()
{
    return "{$this['name']} {$this['lastname']}";
}
```

and then, I add it in appends:

```
class User extends Authenticatable {
    protected $appends = ['fullname'];
}
```

What do you think?

Comment: i think is not what i search

Answer (score 1):

In your model write a function to concatenate the name

```
public function getFullNameAttribute() {
        return ucfirst($this->first_name) . ' ' . ucfirst($this->last_name);
    }
```

now you can call it this way

```
$user = User::find(1);
echo $user->full_name;

or 
Auth::user()->full_name;
```